# Incorrect PSQL command puts sql in a state that cannot be exited unless exiting from PSQL completely

Tags: postgresql, psql

[image: Cannot exit from incorrect query]

As you can see I did not quote Hill correctly thus making the SQL command incorrect. The first SQL line has the database name followed by `=#` the second line has `-#`. After the incorrect SQL command there is `'#`.

The issue is no matter what, I cannot exit the `'#`.

Only option is to quit psql with `\q`. Is there a way to go back from `'#` to `=#` instead of completely exiting psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'#` tells you there is a dangling quote.

To finish the statement enter `');` on the `'#` prompt.

The `'` closes the string. The `)` ends the VALUES part of the INSERT and the `;` ends the whole statement resulting in a syntax error (obviously)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my hands, you can't even use \q to quit, as that can be a legitimate part of a single-quote quoted string.  I just get a message (on Linux) saying `Use control-D to quit.`, which does work.

But to get out of the line entry without closing psql, another thing that you can do is hitting ctrl-C.  (But this doesn't work on MSWindows, it bombs all the way out of psql).  The problem with that is that you lose your buffer.

If you want to preserve your query buffer so you can go back and edit it to fix the problem, then do as the horse suggests and just close the quote and whatever other open constructs you have, to get the syntax error.  Then hit the up arrow to go edit it, adding the missing quote in the proper place and deleting the extra one you had to add at the end to get things to close out.  To be really careful, you should make sure the thing you are about to submit really is going to be a syntax error, and not accidentally a valid statement which does something you don't want.  When attached to production, I take the ctrl-C route and accept the loss of the query buffer, it is safer.